# jQuery, using .load() how to ignore Google Analytics

Tags: jquery

I'm using .load() for some functions on my website, however is there a way to have it ignore my Google Analytics code and not wait for it?

Answer (score 0):

you can asynchronously load the google analytics code instead of embedding it in your markup.

Also, I created a code snippet to do what you are asking previously:

https://github.com/neilfarted/JS/blob/master/GoogleAnalytics

It has the addition of event tracking, but you can discard that part if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider putting the code that inits and calls Google Analytics inside the function for the onload event itself. You could put it after your own code if that is desirable.